# Quicklisp loads library but is nowhere to be found in *features*

Tags: common-lisp, asdf, quicklisp

Today I installed cl-html-parse with Quicklisp but when I load it the library is nowhere to be found in the *features* list, what's going on?
I thought that it may have been a bug with Quicklisp so I did a (asdf-install:install :cl-html-parse) and compiled everything, once again nothing is to be found in *features*.

(require :cl-html-parse) returns NIL
(ql:quickload "cl-html-parse") returns:
"
To load "cl-html-parse":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-html-parse
; Loading "cl-html-parse"

("cl-html-parse")"

I have installed other libraries with Quicklisp before, everything worked fine then. I've tried updating the client and I was already on the latest version.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, my CL implementation is SBCL 1.0.49.

EDIT:
TL;DR:
The problem is that I have a library which supposedly gets loaded into Common Lisp but is unusable and I want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cl-html-parse doesn't push any symbols onto *features* that I can see. I did a quick search of the cl-html-parse source files and don't see the word "feature" in any of them.

Comment: But the whole point of *features* is to show what packages are currently loaded in your Common Lisp session (if you can call it that). CL-html-parse is almost a direct port of Franz Inc.:s version of it, doesn't it seem a little silly for Industrial Grade software not push any symbols onto features? I'm also rather sure that this is done automatically.


Furthermore, I can't access any of the packages functions either as it says that that package does not exist.

Comment: You're mistaken. That's not the point of `*features*` at all. Perhaps you're thinking of `*modules*`, which interacts with `require`. But neither `*features*` nor `*modules*` are directly related to loading software with ASDF.

Comment: Well, I wasn't talking about loading software with ASDF but could you please explain to me what *features* is supposed to do then?

Comment: See [the spec page](http://l1sp.org/cl/*features*) for exactly what `*features*` is for. It's especially useful in conjunction with #+ and #-, see *Notes* in the spec for some info.